# Foundry skip compilation on test

Tags: solidity, foundry

Is it possible somehow to skip compilation when testing with foundry? I have a lot of contracts in the src map but there is only 1 file in a test map and whenever I run `foundry test` the compilation takes above 3 minutes to wait because it compiles all files from src however I don't need them.
In foundry.toml I do have a field - test = 'test/foundry'. I tried to specify contract/test/path like `forge test --match-contract test.t.sol --math-test testHash` but it doesn't help.
So whenever I change any letter in the test file I have to wait around 3 minutes. Any thoughts?

Would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We recently added `forge build --skip <...>`. So you can do `forge build --skip test` [link](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1608456940593496068?s=20&t=dowxwsBp95D7zXV6_YvT5g) and that will only compile `src/`.

We also recently [trimmed down](https://twitter.com/msolomon44/status/1603880725228703744?s=20&t=dowxwsBp95D7zXV6_YvT5g) forge-std for v1.2 so compilation times with `via-ir` should be down as well.

LMK if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because of via-ir changes.

See [this](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/ir-breaking-changes.html)

You can try to revert foundry to v0.3 with

```
forge install foundry-rs/forge-std@c19dfd2f2a88a461216b0dd1f4961e1a85dcad46
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on the opensea project. I suppose they had a similar problem so in the foundry.toml they specified a new profile - profile.test where they override the src field from 'contracts' to 'test/foundry' so whenever you want to run tests just set the environment variable FOUNDRY_PROFILE="test" and just run them. It will compile only files from test/foundry.

```
[profile.default]
src = 'contracts'
```

---

```
[profile.test]
src = 'test/foundry'
```

---

**For windows**

```
$env:FOUNDRY_PROFILE = "test"
```

---

```
forge test
```